# How to draw a intersection of two cones graphically

Tags: geometry

What is the best software we can use to draw the intersections of two cones such as ellipses and hyperbolas mathematically and clearly.

Please send some drawaings and software you have used?

Comment: Best software? Mathematica. Then ask here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you really want the intersection between two cones? The usual way to get ellipses and hyperbolas is to intersect a cone with a plane. It's certainly possible to get them from the intersection between two cones, but not a usual approach to these curves.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Best software is "Grapher" on Macintosh in the utilities folder.

Comment: but intersections are not clear, how do we make it clearer?

Comment: There are three cones that are orthogonal, they are pairwise tangent but have a triple point of intersection only at the origin. Plus, you can move the image around to get the view you need. Plus... if you have a Macintosh it's free!